# Does proofing time depend on the quantity of dough?

Tags: dough, recipe-scaling, dumplings, proofing

One recipe, for example, specifies the dough should be left to rise for 4 hours. If I make halt the amount of dough, will the proofing time change? 
I'm not providing the recipe because I will be trying and experimenting with many in the next few days.

Comment: Are we talking about yeast-based recipes? (See why adding the recipe may least get the discussion started in the right direction?)

Comment: @stephie- Do you proof your chemically risen dough? This question is not about a single recipe and including a recipe would be distracting. IMO most questions are not improved by including the recipe.

Comment: @Sobachatina We may also be dealing with language imprecision - many dumpling wrappers are completely without leavening (not unlike pasta dough) and would need a *resting* period. Just trying to clarify what exactly we are talking about.

Comment: Fair enough. The question stated they were left to rise. Seems very clear to me. Either way- the question is about rising in general and not about this particular recipe.

Comment: @Sobachatina learned to assume very little and ask for clarification just to double-check. Like your answer, btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

The proofing time of a dough is a function of the ratio of yeast and available water, and the temperature of the dough. Notice these are ratios. If you doubled a recipe but didn't double the yeast with it the dough would rise much more slowly.

The quantity of dough will only play a role in rise time if the dough is a significantly different temperature than the surrounding environment. In this case the dough in the center will rise at a different rate than the dough on the outside.